# How to check if any object in an array has a property in Azure Logic App

Tags: c#, azure, linq, azure-logic-apps, azure-resource-manager

I am building a Azure Logic App which recieves vouchers array. I need to parse the body and stop execution if any voucher has the property `canBeUsed` to true. For achieving I want to use `until` instead of `forEach` because If I find any voucher with the property to `true` I want to stop iterating, I dont need to keep iterating.

In `c#` I would do this `return response.Any(b => b.CanBeUsed);`

The JSON received:

```
{
  "vouchers": [
    {
      "amountPending": {
        "currency": {
          "code": "EUR",
          "symbol": "€",
          "id": 978
        },
        "amount": 1517
      },
      "amountPendingWithoutBonus": {
        "currency": {
          "code": "EUR",
          "symbol": "€",
          "id": 978
        },
        "amount": 1517
      },
      "canBeUsed": false,
      "cannotBeUsedReasons": [],
      "firstName": "jason",
      "lastName": "denis",
      "expirationDate": "2021-11-30T00:00:00",
      "issuedDate": "2020-05-31T00:00:00",
      "issuedReason": "Cancellation",
      "voucherType": "Covid19",
      "usages": []
    },
    {
      "amountPending": {
        "currency": {
          "code": "EUR",
          "symbol": "€",
          "id": 123
        },
        "amount": 134
      },
      "amountPendingWithoutBonus": {
        "currency": {
          "code": "EUR",
          "symbol": "€",
          "id": 9718
        },
        "amount": 551
      },
      "canBeUsed": true,
      "cannotBeUsedReasons": [],
      "firstName": "paul",
      "lastName": "frank",
      "expirationDate": "2021-12-30T00:00:00",
      "issuedDate": "2020-09-31T00:00:00",
      "issuedReason": "Cancellation",
      "voucherType": "Covid19",
      "usages": []
    }
  ]
}
```

What I have done:

[image]
[image]

I am stuck on accessing to the array inside the `Until Customer Has Not Vouchers That Can Be Used`.

I want to achieve this:

```
HasVouchersThatCanBeUsed = vouchers[i].canBeTrue;
```

Comment: what is the class used to deserialize your json?

Comment: Based on your requirement shared above , we have create a logic app in our environment understood that we can use foreach loop for access the json object values from the http output  & to perform further  validation by using the until inside the foreach as shown in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADEWG.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Filter array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#filter-array-action) action to filter the **vouchers** array by `@item()?['canBeUsed']` equal to `@true`. Then you can check if the result array is empty.

You don't need the loop, unless you want to process the array items individually.